# Down sample DF1 according to the coordinates in DF2

Tags: python, pandas

I have two DataFrames. Both have X and Y coordinates. But DF1 is much denser than DF2. I want to downsample DF1 according to the X Y coordinates in DF2. Specifically, for each X/Y pairs in DF2, I select DF1 data between X +/-delta and Y +/-delta, and calculate the average value of Z. New_DF1 will have the same X Y coordinate as DF2, but with the average value of Z by downsampling.

Here are some examples and a function I made for this purpose. My problem was that it is too slow for a large dataset. It is highly appreciated if anyone has a better idea to vectorize the operation instead of crude looping.

Create data examples:

```
DF1 = pd.DataFrame({'X':[0.6,0.7,0.9,1.1,1.3,1.8,2.1,2.8,2.9,3.0,3.3,3.5],"Y":[0.6,0.7,0.9,1.1,1.3,1.8,2.1,2.8,2.9,3.0,3.3,3.5],'Z':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]})
DF2 = pd.DataFrame({'X':[1,2,3],'Y':[1,2,3],'Z':[10,20,30]})
```

Function:

```
def DF1_match_DF2_target(half_range, DF2, DF1):
    ### half_range, scalar, define the area of dbf target
    ### dbf data
    ### raw pwg pixel map
    DF2_X =DF2.loc[:,["X"]]
    DF2_Y =DF2.loc[:,['Y']]
    results = list()
    for i in DF2.index:
        #Select target XY from DF2
        x= DF2_X.at[i,'X']
        y= DF2_Y.at[i,'Y']

        #Select X,Y range for DF1
        upper_lmt_X = x+half_range
        lower_lmt_X = x-half_range
        upper_lmt_Y = y+half_range
        lower_lmt_Y = y-half_range

        #Select data from DF1 according to X,Y range, calculate average Z
        subset_X = DF1.loc[(DF1['X']>lower_lmt_X) & (DF1['X']<upper_lmt_X)]
        subset_XY = subset_X.loc[(subset_X['Y']>lower_lmt_Y) & (subset_X['Y']<upper_lmt_Y)]
        result = subset_XY.mean(axis=0,skipna=True)
        result[0] = x #set X,Y in new_DF1 the same as the X,Y in DF2
        result[1] = y #set X,Y in new_DF1 the same as the X,Y in DF2
        results.append(result)
    results = pd.DataFrame(results)
    return results
```

Test and Result:

```
new_DF1 = DF1_match_DF2_target(0.5,DF2,DF1)
new_DF1
```

[Test and Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwnIX.png)

Answer (score 0):

How about using the 'pandas:cut()' function to aggregate using the boundary values?

```
half_range = 0.5
# create bins
x_bins = [0] + list(df2.x)
y_bins = [0] + list(df2.y)
tmp = [half_range]*(len(df2)+1)

x_bins = [a + b for a, b in zip(x_bins, tmp)]
y_bins = [a + b for a, b in zip(y_bins, tmp)]

key = pd.cut(df1.x, bins=x_bins, right=False, precision=1)
df3 = df1.groupby(key).mean().reset_index()
df2.z = df3.z

df2
x   y   z
0   1   1   3.0
1   2   2   6.5
2   3   3   9.5
```

Comment: thanks for your comment! I'm pretty new to python and pandas so it's great to learn this pandas.cut function. However, there are a couple of questions. 1) if we use half-range as 0.3, then the bin becomes [0.3,1.3), [1.3, 2.3), [2.3, 3.3). While the expectation is [0.7,1.3), [1.7, 2.3), etc.. 2)the X, Y coordinates in New_DF1 is also average value, where I want to have the same X,Y coordinates as in DF2. Is there a way to substitute X,Y in New_DF1?

Comment: Q1: I think the 'pandas:cut' function can only support consecutive segment values. The classification value here is specified as '[0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5]'.
Q2: I want to modify a code that has already been submitted.